# How do I list all files of a directory?

Tags: python, list, file, directory

```py
import os
 
print("Python Program to print list the files in a directory.")
 
Direc = input(r"Enter the path of the folder: ")
print(f"Files in the directory: {Direc}")
 
files = listdir(Direc)
files = [f for f in files if os.path.isfile(Direc+'/'+f)] #Filtering only the files.
print(*files, sep="\n")
```

Comment: Why not use *pathlib* `Path` instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

Comment: Since Python 3.6+  it has *pathlib* to handle the file ops.  (OOP concept) - it's recommended way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `isfile()` function from the `os.path` module to check whether an element is a file or a directory:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
```

Or search for other alternatives as well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory).